# HTML in JSON parses as plain text

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

So I'm working on a WordPress theme that's pretty ajax'd, and I'm parsing the data from the requested post into an encoded json, printing it, and then parsing it using json.parse.

Afterwards, I'm using handlebars to display the data in a modal. However at this point, I see the content as well as the HTML in plain text.

Here is my PHP function to get the posts data:

```
function loadPostContent() {

    $pid        = intval($_POST['post_id']);
    $the_query  = new WP_Query(array('p' => $pid, 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 6));

    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $data = json_encode(get_post());
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo '<div id="postdata">'.__('Didnt find anything', THEME_NAME).'</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    print($data);
    die();
}
```

It returns as a json strong with the HTML in it.

Here is the code that requests the json:

```
$('.work-item a').on('click', function(event){
    getPostData($(this).data('post-id'));
    return false;
});

function getPostData(postId) {
    console.log('The post id is: ' + postId);
    $.post(ajaxurl, {
        action: 'loadPostContent',
        post_id: postId,
    }, function(data, textStatus, x) {
        console.log(data);
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        handleTemplate(response);
    });
}

function handleTemplate(response){
    console.log(response);
    var source = $('#single-post-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = {
        title: response.post_title,
        excerpt: response.post_excerpt,
        content: response.post_content
    };
    $('body').after(template(context));
    handleModal('#single-post-modal');
}

function handleModal(modalId) {
     $(modalId).openModal();
}
```

At this point, the content renders, but everything is in plain text. How can I render the HTML that is in the JSON values?

Answer (score 0):

the thing is, you are writing that JSON response after the body of your HTML and not inside of it... try this instead:

```
function handleTemplate(response){
 console.log(response);
 var source = $('#single-post-template').html(), template = Handlebars.compile(source), 
 context = {
    title: response.post_title,
    excerpt: response.post_excerpt,
    content: response.post_content
 };
 $('body').html(template(context));
 handleModal('#single-post-modal');
}
```

If you have another container to put the info in just replace `$('body)` with it...

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but replaced body with an empty div called #template-placeholder. It's still showing the html as plain text.